# I need help unlocking my bootloader on my galaxy note 9 sm-n960u using kali linux 2021.4

Tags: rooting, root-access, custom-roms, lineageos, bootloader-lock

I need help unlocking my bootloader on my galaxy note 9 sm-n960u using kali linux 2021.4 iv'e tried window and android to unlock bootloader so that's why i am asking with help doing it with linux it has android OS 10 with one UI2.5 so if anyone could help out i would appreciate it Ty.

Comment: search for vaultkeeper

Comment: fyi the last [user](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:359890) who insisted in **not** using windows finally hard-bricked his device by accidentially downgrading bootloader

Comment: US variants can't be unlocked in regular ways. If you insist, see [UnSamLock](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/android-unsamlock-bootloader-unlock-for-samsung-us-canada-devices.4215101/) (paid).